# How to add and remove the cls in the action column of the grid dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I want to add and remove the cls of the action column in the grid dynamically.

Can any one help me in doing this?

Comment: To improve your odds of getting help from people here, I suggest you go back to your previous questions here on SO and 'accept' or upvote the ones that have helped you before asking new questions. Keep in mind that if none of the answers to a particular question help you  you can post your own answer/findings (once you have it off course-:)) and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to not use an actioncolumn actually.  Use a normal column and render the image you want and then have a hander for the column click, here is code actually used in my application for a single column:

```
   {
                width: 25,
                renderer: function(value, metaData, record){
                    if(record.get("node_type") == "CONDITION")
                        return "<img src=\"magnifier.png\"/>";
                    return "";
                },
                listeners: {
                    click: function(grid, htmlRow, index, columnIndex, mouseEvent, record){
                                         //do something here
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: But , if i want to more than one image.